# Ошибка Access Not Configured при попытке подключения к google API

Tags: html, google-api, youtube-api

У меня не получается обратиться через javascript к YouTube API (хотя на самом деле я начал делать через php (с другим ключём), но там возникает аналогичная ошибка).

1. Я создал приложение в консоли разработчика и API-ключ к нему (браузерный, без привязки доменов).
2. Подключил YouTube Data API v3.
3. Создал HTML (скопировал из [вот этого](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples?hl=ru) примера).

Но мне в качестве ответа выдается вот такая ошибка:

> > `[
> >     {
> >         "error": {
> >             "code": 403,
> >             "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.",
> >             "data": [
> >                 {
> >                     "domain": "usageLimits",
> >                     "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
> >                     "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
> >                 }
> >             ]
> >         },
> >         "id": "gapiRpc"
> >     }
> > ]`

Подскажите, что я делаю не так или хотя бы в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 1):

Доступ не определен (не сконфигурирован).
Нужно проверить еще раз ключи, `client_id`, `client_secret` и их реализацию в json файле, если вы его используете.
Далее проверить, что указано в доступе в "Public API access", если вы не используете конкретный домен, то укажите ip-адреса, в частности 127.0.0.1 и порт, если есть необходимость.

Хотя... вопрос был задан давно и автор уже нашел решение.